# Как вывести реальные дату и время

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Не могу понять как с помощью библиотеки time.h выести реальные дату и время

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[этот ресурс](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) тебе поможет

```
/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts, printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime */

 int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  printf ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime(timeinfo));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Код не пашет.
Error 1 error C4996: 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. c:\users\дмитрий\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication6\consoleapplication6\localtime.cpp 11

Comment: [C4996](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx) — это warning. _Ваш К. О._

---
И да, если вы не можете прочитать текст сообщения компилятора и переделать пример на `localtime_s`, у вас гораздо более серьёзная проблема.